# Insert Front-End Library (eg. Analytics): why not a simple <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, insert

In order to insert GA code (and pretty much any other JS library), the code snippet is:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Why not:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async></script>
```

at the end of the `body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google knows that the script they have is not dependent on any other script in the page, therefore they are enforcing that the script is executed as 'non-blocking' meaning that the script content is executed ASAP, outside of the usual  tag ordering within the document (it does not have any dependencies).

The [implementation of the DOM script tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script) is non-trivial and must cater for script inter-dependencies, unless explicitly stated as '[async](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async)'. In this case the external code will be executed immediately, without waiting for anything else on the page to load.

[Google have documented their approach well here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced). Basically it will improve performance on old browsers by allowing `async` script execution. Dynamically inserting a script tag mimics the behaviour of the native `async` attribute in modern browsers. You can see that the dynamic script tag is marked as `async` in their code injector function, to cater for modern browsers too.

i.e. `a.async=1;`

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned in the comments, Google are simply providing an idiot-proof script block with maximum browser support.

Specifically, the **async** attribute isn't supported in IE9. See http://caniuse.com/#search=script-async

Answer (score 1):

According to Google's [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced), they do recommend the simpler `<script src>` version but **only** if you're targeting modern browsers (excluding IE 9).

Answer (score 0):

The first reason is for some scripts they need to run before the html is created, and the second for it not to be in an external script is that you need to overwrite some values.

```
 ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
```

you have to put your own GA account here so it makes no sense to put such a short script inside a an external file. It is done this way for ease of use so that even beginner devs and non devs can add analytics to a page.

Comment: Regarding your second point, I would do something like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async data-id="UA-XXXXX-X"></script>` which seems even less error-prone to me.

Comment: What you put in the js file to reference it's own script tag to get the data-id?

Comment: Well, you can pick it with `$('script[src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"]');` or its VanillaJS equivalent. Or you could even add a class/ID to it (in case the URL changes....)

Comment: Maybe the library writers feel it is easier to understand for newer on non developers.